# Defining hash value depending on the hash itself in perl

Tags: perl

I want to fix the following code in such a way so as to have the desired output as given below. But i find both the print statements dont work at same time.

**Code:**

```
our %HASH=(
    elem1=>["FD1","FD2",$arr_path[0]],
    elem2=>["FD4","FD5",$arr_path[1]],
);
my @arr_path=(
    "/abc/def/$HASH{elem1}[0].ctrl",
    "/abc/def/$HASH{elem1}[1].ctrl"
);

    print "\nPrinting path from HASH  :". $HASH{"elem1"}[2];
    print "\nPrinting path from arr_path  :". $arr_path[0];
    print "\n";
```

**Obtained output:**

```
Printing path from HASH  :
Printing path from arr_path  :/abc/def/FD1.ctrl
```

**Desired output:**

```
Printing path from HASH  :/abc/def/FD1.ctrl
Printing path from arr_path  :/abc/def/FD1.ctrl
```

Comment: Is `$arr_path` really suppose to be `$HASH{elem1}[1]`, or should it be `$HASH{elem2}[0]`

Comment: @ikegami : well its neither `{elem}[1]` nor `{elem2}[0]`. `$arr_path` Basically always forms the third element of the array(reference).

Comment: huh? In your code, is `$HASH{elem1}[1]` really suppose to be `$HASH{elem2}[0]`?

Comment: @ikegami : No, not at all. As written in the code elem1 is a key which has a value as reference to array containing three elements. All these three elements are different however the third element contains a string and this string is made up from the first element. Please let me know if i confused you more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make two variables that depend on each other.

What you could do is something like:

```
our %HASH=(
  elem1=>["FD1","FD2",],
  elem2=>["FD4","FD5",],
);
my @arr_path=(
    "/abc/def/$HASH{elem1}[0].ctrl",
    "/abc/def/$HASH{elem1}[1].ctrl"
);

$HASH{elem1}[2] = $arr_path[0];
$HASH{elem2}[2] = $arr_path[1];
```

but that's a bit confusing.

I think that you need to re-think your data structures and fetch the data from one structure, calculating the dependent information that you need. (If performance is an issue, use memoization.)

Comment: Would be clearer if you got rid of `@arr_path` entirely.

Comment: @Rob : Thanks Rob. It helped me. I think its same as `elem1=>["FD1","FD2",undef], elem2=>["FD4","FD5",undef] `